# The best way to test if a returned string is null in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a function that concatenate a set of strings like this:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

sb.append(fct1());
sb.append(fct2());
sb.append(fct3());
```

Where fct1(), fct2() and fct3() should return a String.
The problem is that I must test the returned values like this :

```
sb.append(fct1() == null ? "" : fct1());
```

because I get an exception if the value is null.

The problem is that I have many instructions like this and, above all, I can't modify these functions that return the strings(fct1, fct2 and fct3).

Is there a solution that will "sanitize" automatically my strings?

Thank you.

PS: I created a function that can do it:

```
public String testNullity(String aString){
aString == null ? "" : aString;
}
```

so that I can call it like this:

```
sb.append(testNullity(fct1));
sb.append(testNullity(fct2));
...
```

Comment: StringBugger? Is this some new class? :-)

Comment: So why does your solution not suit you?

Comment: @Howard StringBuffer is final

Comment: Try to redesign your functions so that they do not return null values. That's the *best* way to avoid unexpected NPEs ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another alternative might be

```
 public class SafeStringBuilder  {
    private StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    public SafeStringBuilder append(String s) {
        if (s != null) 
            builder.append(s);
        return this;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Apart from `StringBuilder` being `final`, this is a nice idea. (Use delegation instead.)

Comment: Does not work, StringBuilder is final. Try the wrapper solution! (Edit: +1 for Paulo for being 11 seconds faster than me :))

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind introducing a dependency, use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Joiner`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) instead of `StringBuffer`:

```
Joiner j = Joiner.on("").skipNulls();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
j.appendTo(sb, fct1());
j.appendTo(sb, fct2());
j.appendTo(sb, fct3());
String result = sb.toString();

// or even just
Joiner j = Joiner.on("").skipNulls();
String result = j.join(fct1(), fct2(), fct3());
```

---

N.B. In general, unless you need [`StringBuffer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)'s thread safety, you should use [`StringBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead. Same API, better performance.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing whatsoever you can do to make this solution simpler except shortening the method name. (There might be a solution using aspect-oriented programming, but on the whole I don't really consider that simpler.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your solution with `testNullity()` is the best you can get with Java (consider better naming though). In fact, there is already a method that does that: [StringUtils.html#defaultString](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#defaultString%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own wrapper around `StringBuffer`:

```
class MyStringBuffer {
    StringBuffer _sb = new StringBuffer();
    public boolean append(String s) {
        _sb.append(s==null ? "" : s);
        return s == null;
    }
    public String toString() { return _sb.toString(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function in the standard API, though some methods (which do other things) have it built in.

For example, [System.getProperty()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) has a variant which takes a default value, and if it can't find the given property, it will not return `null`, but the given default value. You might think of providing your `fct*` methods with such a "default" argument, if it makes sence.

I think C# has a `??` operator which does about what you want (you would call `sb.append(fct2() ?? "")`), but I suppose Java will not add any new operators soon.

A better variant of your checking function would be this:

```
public void appendIfNotNull(StringBuffer sb, String s) {
    if(s != null) {
       sb.append(s);
    }
}
```

This avoids the superfluous append call with an empty string if there is nothing to append.